# The getter 'length' was called on null in post request

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a post request to an API, and I couldn't get why this is happening.
This is my code:

```
  print('THIS IS PRINTING');
  var response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: header);
  print('This not printing (throwing error before it prints)');
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

> ```
> I/flutter ( 2417): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
> I/flutter ( 2417): Receiver: null
> I/flutter ( 2417): Tried calling: length
> ```

I'm able to make the request using PostMan, and giving the same fields and values, I get this error on dart. I'm also able to make other get requests without any issues.

Full code:

```
void getFavorites() async {
  var url = "https://www.my-url-edited.com/favorite";

  var header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "token": "my token ---- edited",
  };


  var body = {
    "car_id": "1",
    "boat_id": null,
    "habitation_id": null,
    "product_id": null,
  };

  try {
    print('print before post request --- working');
    // var response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: header);
    var response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: header);
    print('This not printing (throwing error before it prints)');
    print(response.body);
    // var data = json.decode(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    throw Exception('Not connected to network');
  }
}
```

Comment: show code of length

Comment: there's no variable called `length` in my code, what do you mean?

Comment: Is there anywhere you invoked `.length` ?

Comment: @Locked No, there's not. it's just a button that makes this API request and for now i'm just trying to print the `response.body`

Comment: Can you please add your full code?

Comment: I think the error occurs when u call response before it is initialized. Try putting them to a future function.

Comment: can you show us the status of respons by response.statusCode

Comment: @Merym The error seems to be from the post request, the code doesn't go further. I can't print the `response.statusCode` because it throws an error

Comment: @Vitor Try my answer

Answer (score 1):

you header should be ,

```
headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "token": "my token ---- edited",
};

var body = jsonEncode({
    "car_id": "1",
  });
```